# C# - Using FN+Fkeys with SendKey?

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendkeys

So, I've created an on screen keyboard which is working great - except on my current keyboard I press FN and F1 (for example) and my screen brightness increases. F2 decreases, F5 turns backlit keyboard on/off etc etc

Can I recreate this on my keyboard? I thought maybe there would be someway of seeing how it works currently and adding that to my code? But I'm just a beginner so I don't really know.

I don't imagine there is a SendKeys parameter to handle this, so is there a work around?

Cheers!

Comment: I can never find them when I search. Thanks, that question solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The FN key modifies the key code being sent. So to do this (since the FN key acts as a hardware modifier as opposed to ALT, SHIFT, etc.) you could create a MessageBox that displays the key code whenever you press a key and use the values it gives you with [these codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=VS.85).aspx)